# CKEditor is not escaping single quotes to its corresponding htmlentity in <img> tag's alt attribute

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor 4.5.11. When I try to insert some data which contains following markup:

```
<img src="/images/nature.jpg" alt="Nature at it's best" border="0" />
```

my PHP/MySQL code gets crashed. It can't insert data in database. We know that CKEditor escapes single quote into `&#39;` but in `<img>` tag it gets failed. Why? What is the workaround - I mean in config.js?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the CKEditor translate the single-quote or not - you should **always** [escape code](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) that you send to your MySQL server, otherwise your code is vulnerable to sql-injections.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() creates a lot of problems of data coming from a ckeditor instance. I personally don't use it for any ckeditor input.

Comment: You should learn how to use it since it shouldn't have any problems :)